# stunnel is not accepting incoming request from other machine

Tags: ssl, quickfix, stunnel

I have Machine A where stunnel is running. I am sending data on port of Machine A from Machine B but stunnel is not listening this port when request comes from different machine. It works fine when I send request on same port from local machine.

Stunnel setting on Machine A is like this:

```
[MyConn]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:3500
connect=67.68.90.73:5510
```

Machine B

Application is sending data on port 3500 of Machine A:

```
SocketConnectHost=MachineA
SocketConnectPort=3500
```

But I don't see any request coming in stunnel from Machine B, I have also checked that when I run tcplistener on Machine A, request is coming from Machine B. It seems issues with stunnel application. Please suggest is there any configuration or setting needed in stunnel.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is the local machine. You have restricted connections which can be accepted to the local machine only.

You can run stunnel in inetd mode (inetd starts stunnel up when a connection attempt arrives), or the preferred daemon mode. Refer to the stunnel [HOWTO](https://www.stunnel.org/howto.html) for more details. Here's what you do for daemon mode.

First add the following line to /etc/services:

```
myconn       3500/tcp                # name the service
```

Stunnel configuration file needs at least the section name and accept option. For example:

```
[myconn service]
accept = myconn
...
```